# Strange conversion from float to int

Tags: c++

```
for(float i = 40; i <= 42; i+=0.1f)
{
    float offset = (i-40) * 10 * sizeof(float);
    int wtf = offset;
    printf("%.1f =?= %d\n", offset, wtf);
    fseek(fin, offset, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&tf, sizeof(float), 1, fin);
    //printf("%.1f %.4f\n", i, tf);
}
```

Output:

> 0.0 =?= 0
>   4.0 =?= 3
>   8.0 =?= 7
>   12.0 =?= 11
>   16.0 =?= 15
>   20.0 =?= 19
>   24.0 =?= 23
>   28.0 =?= 27
>   32.0 =?= 31
>   36.0 =?= 35
>   40.0 =?= 39
>   44.0 =?= 43
>   48.0 =?= 47
>   52.0 =?= 51
>   56.0 =?= 55
>   60.0 =?= 59
>   64.0 =?= 63
>   68.0 =?= 67
>   72.0 =?= 71
>   76.0 =?= 75
>   80.0 =?= 79

I dont understand this, can you help me?

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: I highly encourage you to read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `0.1` isn't exactly representable as a binary floating-point number. Each `float` value is slightly less than you expect, and conversion to `int` rounds down, giving a value one less than you expect.

You can get the expected values by rounding to the nearest integer:

```
int wtf = std::round(offset);
```

Answer (score 1):

when `i = 40.1f` offset will be `3.99993896` which is not exactly 4. For your example you can use `std::round(offset)` if you use c++11 standard or if round is not available `std::floor(offset + 0.5f);`

Floating points can't represent all the values in the universe and when in some cases the math  on papers is correct on floating points it might not be.

Answer (score 0):

0.1 expressed in base 2 is

```
0.0001100110011001100110011001100110011...
```

The `0011` in the fraction repeats infinitely, just as `3` does in 1/3=0.3333333... base 10. Since actual float values can only hold a finite number of digits, there will necessarily be an error in the approximation.

The only fractional numbers that can be precisely expressed with a finite number of digits in base 2 are those rational numbers whose denominator is a whole power of 2. So for example, replacing 0.1f with 0.125f (=1/8)

```
for(float i = 40; i <= 42; i+=0.125f)
{
    float offset = (i-40) * 10 * sizeof(float);
    int wtf = offset;
    printf("%.1f =?= %d\n", offset, wtf);
}
```

results in values with no truncation error:

```
0.0 =?= 0
5.0 =?= 5
10.0 =?= 10
15.0 =?= 15
20.0 =?= 20
25.0 =?= 25
30.0 =?= 30
35.0 =?= 35
40.0 =?= 40
45.0 =?= 45
50.0 =?= 50
55.0 =?= 55
60.0 =?= 60
65.0 =?= 65
70.0 =?= 70
75.0 =?= 75
80.0 =?= 80
```

This is because `0.125` base 10 is precisely equal to `0.001` base 2.